# if condition in gnuplot for the third axis

Tags: gnuplot

I want to make a plot of a file in palette format,

```
plot 'file.dat' u ($3-$10):($196-$203):($196=$203) pointtype 1 lc palette,\
     'file.dat' u ($7-$14):($200-$207):($200=$207) pointtype 1 lc palette
```

Whereas the choice of the columns is not regular, I need to use an `if` condition for the palette axis (bar) which indicates that if column `$196=$203` plot column `$196` or if `$200=$207` plot `$200`.

I don't know whether this is possible in `gnuplot` or I should skip using `gnuplot`.

Comment: I don't what the palette format is.  Can you point me to a url or give example data that illustrate the problem?  200+ columns probably mean you should simplify it.  gnuplot allows you to select columns by name in case that helps `using (column("Age")):(column(1))`

Comment: If $196=$203 or $200=$207 what do you want to happen in (a) false and (b) true?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977969/doing-calculations-in-gnuplots-plot-command if you haven't yet.

Comment: @AllanWind There is no true or false, only choosing the numbers when column 196 is equal to column 203, and  when column 200 is equal to column 207.

Comment: Meaning you want to ignore the data point if  $196=$203 or $200=$207?  In that case see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359253/how-do-i-skip-rows-in-gnuplot-when-plotting-a-heat-map

Comment: @dove have you checked help ternary? 
Please specify what should be plotted if `$196==$203` and what should be plotted if `$196!=$203`? Do you want to have a point plotted or not, or just in different color if the condition is met? 
What do you mean with 3rd axis? Do you want to have a 3D x,y,z plot? Then check `help splot`.

Comment: @theozh Well, I want to choose either `$196` or `$203`, if `$196==$203`. And by the third axis I mean the color palette bar.

Comment: @dove I'm still confused. What should be the color of the datapoint if `$196==$203` and what should be the color of the data point if `$196!=$203`? Please provide some minimal data (maybe not 200 columns) and an illustrative sketch to explain what you would like to have. I guess it's not the problem that gnuplot cannot do it but the problem seems to be that from your description I don't understand what you would like to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I still don't get your point. That's what I've understood so far.
You take some operation of some columns to determine the x- and y-coordinates (in your case: `$3-$10` and `$196-$203`).
And now, you want to determine the color of the datapoint by what? By some condition?
What is the condition? So, what color do you want if the condition is met (`$196==$203`) and what color do you want to have if the condition is not met (i.e. `$196!=$203`).

I order to get any further, I made a minimal example *with* data and with *graph*.
If the value in column 3 is equal to the value in column 4 the color of the datapoint will be according to the palette using column 3, and `NaN` (= not plotted) otherwise. Is this coming close to what you want to achieve? Maybe we can go on from this...

**Code:**

```
### conditional plotting
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1   21  1  0
2   22  2  2
3   23  3  0
4   24  4  4
5   25  5  0
6   26  6  6
7   27  7  0
EOD

set palette rgb 33,13,10

plot $Data u ($1+$2):($3+$4):($3==$4 ? $4 : NaN) w p pt 7 ps 3 lc palette notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: your example was exactly what I meant. This solved my problem thank you so much :)

Comment: glad to hear we came to a solution. Sometimes is difficult to describe and understand  ;-)